# Найти ближайший по значению элемент массива

Tags: статистика, статический-анализ

Доброго дня, коллеги!

Есть массив типа:

```
{
    "h": 45.37,
    "c": 44.03,
    "l": 47.57
},
{
    "h": 43.22,
    "c": 42.34,
    "l": 41.55
}
```

Какой алгоритм в данном случае применить, чтобы найти ближайший элемент из этого массива по заданным трем величинам? Какой обладает максимальной точностью, если вообще можно говорить о точности в данном случае?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, смотря что из себя представляют данные...

```
=sqrt(abs(h1-h)^2)+sqrt(abs(c1-c)^2+abs(l1-l)^2)^2)
```

http://www.codecogs.com/gif.latex?d=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}

Comment: каждый элемент массива это значение цвета в формате LCH. А алгоритм как называется?

Comment: Это расстояние между двумя точками в трехмерном пространстве.

Comment: То что надо! Благодарю!

Comment: В интернете посмотри, как вычислить, я мог неправильно написать, давно с математикой не связывался ))
P.S. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Мог написать неправильно и написал.)) ABS() - тут совершенно ни при чем. Зато, понял смысл вопроса, а я так и не разобрался ((

Comment: Да, вы правы, раз возводим в квадрат,  то модуль не нужен.

Comment: @BuilderC цвет в формате LCH есть не что иное как координаты в трехмерном пространстве. Поэтому, по счастливой случайности, предоставленое решение именно то, что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

[Если все еще интересно](http://users.livejournal.com/_darkus_/655190.html)

У этой задачи множество решений, самых разных по сложности, эффективности, соотношению между сложностью и эффективностью... Могу выложить свое, ИМХО самое лучшее. :)

Comment: Оно всегда интересно! А линк не работает у меня :(

Comment: http://ideone.com/3e7Aee